# Pivot Table adding "2" to value in Report Filter

Tags: vba, excel

I have a file with pivot tables where the filter values are updated on a monthly basis based on the last month's date. VBA code for this:

```
Dim SelectDate As String

SelectDate = Worksheets("Raw").Range("A3").Value
Worksheets("Main").PivotTables("PivotTable4").PivotFields("Date").CurrentPage = SelectDate
```

The value in cell A3 is string based on the following function:

> =A1&" "&A2
> For example: January 2017

Updating the pivot tables worked fine for several months, but for this month my values no longer update correctly and after doing some investigation I realized that my pivot table has created two entries in the filter for the month `January 2017`  and `January 20172`, while `November 2016` went missing:

[image]

However, when I check my underlying data, I only have one value for each month:

```
June 2016
February 2016
March 2016
January 2016
November 2016
December 2016
August 2016
May 2016
October 2016
July 2016
September 2016
April 2016
January 2017
February 2017
```

Note that when I create an new Pivot table with the same data, the filter only shows `January 2017`.

Any suggestions why the filter for the existing pivot table would reflect both `January 2017`  and `January 20172`?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: That's really curious. It's gonna be difficult to reproduce.

Comment: I know, that's why I am worried I won't be able to resolve the issue. But maybe someone else had this issue before and was able to resolve this.

Comment: Can you share sample data?  Does this also happen in a brand-new workbook?

Comment: Weird one for sure. Probably grasping at straws, but did you try qualifying which workbook? E.g. `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")` maybe you have another workbook open with the same sheet names?

Comment: @TimWilliams I haven't tested in a brand-new workbook yet, but good point. I will check that out. In terms of test data, the issue is that the data fills columns A through CU. Any particular part of the data that would be helpful?

Comment: @RyanWildry I will give it a shot and see if it works.

Comment: I guess enough data to reproduce the problem, but we're not really in a position to know how much that would be...  If you can reproduce with a smaller dataset then I would share that.

Comment: Ended up deleting the pivot tables and replacing them with new ones and when I run it now it works fine again. This was really strange.

Comment: But thanks everyone for your help!

Comment: This happened to me (no VBA, just regular pivot table generation) when I changed the name of an entire subset of values. I followed Inet Kemp's proc of re-assigning/re-re-assigning the source data for the table and that worked.

Answer (score 3):

Here is what worked for me. This happened from what I have read elsewhere either because I added now data lines or because I did a find-and-replace. But then I changed the area of the source data in the pivot table from say

```
'MASTER (3)'!$A$5:$EQ$600 to 'MASTER (3)'!$A$5:$EQ$6
```

and then back to

```
'MASTER (3)'!$A$5:$EQ$600
```

This resolved the problem